# Is there a way to combine these 3 attributes into 1 line of code?

Tags: material-ui, typography, react-tsx, makestyles

i am using `import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'`
This is my theme typography config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlYQA.png)

This is file, i want to combine these 3 attributes into 1 line of code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v18V7.png)

Sorry that my English is not good, so it may cause misunderstandings for everyone. Looking forward to support

i want to combine these 3 attributes into 1 line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const a =
     {
      fontSize: theme.typography.text12Medium16.fontSize;
      lineHeight: theme.typography.text12Medium16.lineHeight;
      fontWeight: theme.typography.text12Medium16.fontWeight;
     }
```

this is what you are passing to `MuiDataGrid-main`

and this is your `text12Mediul16` object :

```
const text12Mediul16 =
    {
     fontSize: '12px',
     lineHeight: '16px',
     fontWeight: FONT_MEDIUM   
    }
```

and since :

```
theme.typography.text12Medium16.fontSize = '12px'
theme.typography.text12Medium16.lineHeight = '16px'
theme.typography.text12Medium16.fontWeight = FONT_MEDIUM
```

then `a = text12Mediul16` so you can replace it like this :

```
'& .MuiDataGrid-main: theme.typography.text12Medium16'
```

and if your object contains other properties apart from `fontSize`, `fontWeight` and `lineHeight` that are not shown in your code example, then you can't do better than you did